# Event listeners and hoisting in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoisting

I'm confused about hoisting in js.

I know that functions and variables are moved at the top of the program but what happens with things like "listeners"?

A couple of days ago I was working on something like this:

```
function a(){
  //... 
  $("#myElement").trigger("click");
}

$("#myElement").on("click", function(){
  console.log("click!");
});
```

I realized that If I try to reference an event before its declaration, that reference will be ignored.

So, after changing the order, it worked:

```
$("#myElement").on("click", function(){
   console.log("click!");
});

function a(){
  //... 
  $("#myElement").trigger("click");
}
```

**So, my question is**: why does this last example work if at the end the "a function" is moved at the top (because of hoisting) resulting in something like the first example where that event call didn't work?

Comment: your code works fine either way (once you call `a()` of course - which your code does not)

Comment: I made the correction already. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I removed the reference to that error, but your code works fine either way - how is `a()` getting called? that's what you're doing wrong perhaps

Answer (score 2):

It totally depends on when you call `a()`.  In the end, your event handler just needs to be registered before `trigger()` is executed.  Typically this is resolved with `document.ready(...)`.  See the [jquery documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for an explanation.

```js
function a(){
  //... 
  $("#myElement").trigger("click");
}

$("#myElement").on("click", function(){
   console.log("click!");
});


a();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myElement"/>
```

Comment: is it the same case for the listeners that are created using vanilla js?

Comment: In short: yes.  However, there are some "gotchas" to be aware of.  For example: If you're working with JS and HTML and you try to bind to an HTML element that isn't rendered yet, then the event can't be bound.  It's always best to load your javascript last and wait for the page to be completely loaded before applying listeners.